# Springfox 3.0.0: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous models equality when conditions is empty

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, springfox

I have changed the version of Spring fox to 3.0.0 and using these dependencies:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
   <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
   <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

After that I got below error:

```
ERROR springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper - Unable to scan documentation context default
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous models equality when conditions is empty.
    at springfox.documentation.spring.web.scanners.ApiModelReader.checkCondition(ApiModelReader.java:618)
    at springfox.documentation.spring.web.scanners.ApiModelReader.mergeConditions(ApiModelReader.java:385)
    at springfox.documentation.spring.web.scanners.ApiModelReader.mergeModelBranch(ApiModelReader.java:255)
    at springfox.documentation.spring.web.scanners.ApiModelReader.lambda$read$2(ApiModelReader.java:145)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1382)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
    at springfox.documentation.spring.web.scanners.ApiModelReader.read(ApiModelReader.java:145)
    at springfox.documentation.spring.web.scanners.ApiListingScanner.scan(ApiListingScanner.java:154)
    at springfox.documentation.spring.web.scanners.ApiDocumentationScanner.scan(ApiDocumentationScanner.java:67)
    at springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.AbstractDocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.scanDocumentation(AbstractDocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.java:96)
    at springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.AbstractDocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.bootstrapDocumentationPlugins(AbstractDocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.java:82)
    at springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.start(DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.java:100)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:54)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356)
    at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:155)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:935)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:771)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:763)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:438)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:339)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1329)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1318)
```

I saw https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/3469. It seems that this was a bug of Springfox 3.0.0 and it was fixed, But I still have this problem!! I check it and this error happen when I have some relations in my entity. The question is what can I do now!!??
Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: I've just learned to live with this. Tends to happen once you create relationships, and have one to many/many to one bi-drectional, etc. Doesn't really surface on simple modeling.